# MVVM binding to an array index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I am using MVVM, and I'm trying to bind an array index.  The data context of the XAML control is bound to a view model.  When I instantiate the control, I send the array index into the constructor and then assign that index to a window resource so the XAML can use it directly.  The value is coming through to the constructor as expected, and i can use it in other areas of the XAML page, but for some reason, it will not work as an array index.  Does anyone know what is happening here?

c#:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl {

    public MyControl(int index) {
        MyIndex = index;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int myIndex;
    public int MyIndex {
        get { return myIndex; }
        set { myIndex = value; }
    }

    private void Mygrid_OnLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Resources["myResourceKey"] = MyIndex;
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml:

Define the resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="myResourceKey"></sys:Int32>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This does not work.  I get a binding error because it does not recognize the index

```
 <GradientStop Color="{Binding MyObservableCollection[DynamicResource myResourceKey].ColorsBo.PageBackgroundPrimary}" Offset="1"/>
```

This DOES work, so the resource value is being passed into the xaml:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{DynamicResource myResourceKey}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not a supported syntax - `Binding` does support nested expression, but I think they need to be the whole "value" of a property (like `Source={StaticResource something}`, etc.). In this case you require a nested expression within the `Path` property of the binding and I don't think that is going to work.

Why do you need to bind the array index and can't create a separate property that just returns the `MyObservableCollection[index]` item from the viewmodel?

```
public Item => MyObservableCollection[MyIndex];
```

And in XAML:

```
<GradientStop Color="{Binding Item.ColorsBo.PageBackgroundPrimary}" Offset="1"/>
```

Comment: It REALLY stinks that xaml cant read indexes, but it's great information to know. 
 I can re-work the code to give each control a slice of the data model that is needed.  Thanks a bunch Martin.

Comment: That seems to me like the best approach :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following XAML is invalid:

```
MyObservableCollection[DynamicResource myResourceKey]
```

`DynamicResource myResourceKey` must be replaced with a *constant* like for example `1` or `'abc'`.

The other option is to perform the lookup in the view model as suggested by @Martin Zikmund or use a multi binding that binds to both `myResourceKey` and `MyObservableCollection` and a multi converter:
https://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html